# Disable the Cache Busting in Dynamically Linked External Javascript Files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache, external-js

When loading content through AJAX which contains an externally linked Javascript file or when using jQuery.getScript() function call, the linked Javascript files are appended with a cache busting parameter, which prevents the file from being cached by the browser.

So, instead of writ­ing some­thing like `<script src="/js/foo.js">`, it writes some­thing like `<script src="/js/foo.js?_=ts2477874287">`, caus­ing the script to be loaded fresh each time.

Is there a way to disable this and have the file cached when it's loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about getScript, but `cache` is a parameter you can set in a `.ajax()` parameter map. It's false by default for scripts but you can flip it to true. Once false, it won't append a cache-busting query string.

[updated per comment]

Comment: I think you have the true/false in reverse. Default for cache is true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'. Thus flipping it to true, it should avoid the cache busting parameter? -- They don't seem to have a way to do this in getScript, and unfortunately it still doesn't help me figure out how to override generic `<script>` tags (i.e. not loaded through an ajax call), so the only thing I can currently think of is that I'd have to use jQuery.ajax with cache set to true for all dynamically loaded content with linked external JS files.

Comment: Yes, I had it straight in my head but wrote it down flipped. Thanks! I'm failing to understand what you mean about generic script tags, but that's probably on me.

Comment: Naw, it's on me. I wasn't clear. Assume I'm using `jquery.load('mypage.html');` The mypage.html contains HTML as well as a linked script: `<script src="./js/foo.js">` yet even that gets the cache buster parameter.

Comment: Oh, now that's interesting. Alas I don't know anything about that.